# Investigate the behaviour of a function without computing its second derivative

Tags: analysis, functions

Let a function $f(x)$ be continuous over the interval $[0,\infty]$. For this function we have $f(0)=0$ and $f(a)=0$. Also we have $f(b)>0$, with $b<a$.
Suppose that the only zeros of $f'(x)$ are $x_1$ and $x_2$, where $0<x_1<b<a$ and $x_2>a$. If I am interested on studying the behaviour of $f(x)$ over $[0,a]$, can I claim that this function increases from $0$ to $x_1$ then decreases from  $x_1$ to $a$ ? or I need to compute the second derivative ?

Edit:

Note that $f'(b)<0$.

Comment: I think we have too little information about f(x) to make such claims.

Comment: It might be sufficient to compute the first derivative and study its' sign.

Comment: Do you (maybe) mean that the **only** zeros of $f'$ are at $x_1$ and $x_2$?

Comment: @PhoemueX  yes, exactly!

Comment: Please, consider this additional information: $f'(b)<0$

Comment: If you know that $x_1, x_2$ are the only zeroes of $f^\prime$ and also know that $f^\prime $ is, say, continous, then you can conclude what you proposed.

Comment: You only say that $f$ is continuous. Where does $f'$ exist?

Comment: $f'(x)$ is also continuous over $[0 , \infty]$.. Excuse me but I forgot to mention it..

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen  Thank you for helping me!! One last question (if possible):  An additional information is that $f(x)$ changes concavity at a point between $x_1$ and $a$. Now suppose I have a sum of 3 functions that have the same behaviour as $f(x)$ but with $x_{11}$, $x_{12}$ and $x_{13}$ as the points at which these functions reaches their maximum (all these points are $< a$). Can I claim that the resulting function has the same behaviour as these functions but with a maximum at $x^*$ ($<a$)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can claim that the function is increasing from $0$ to $x_1$ and decreasing from $x_1$ to $a$ . For arriving at this conclusion, you must be sure that function has zeros only at $0$ and $a$ . And also, $f'(x)=0$ only at $x_1$ if $0\lt{x}\lt{a}$ . Here the condition $x\gt{a}$ is not needed.
Then using the fact that $f(b)\gt{0}$ you can find that the function is positive in $\left[0,a\right]$ and here, the extrema is at $x_1$ . And also $x_1\lt{b}$ and $f'(b)\lt{0}$ means it is decreasing.Therefore, it is evident that function is increasing from $0$ to $x_1$ and decreasing from $x_1$ to $a$